# How to stream to NestJS if the data is transmitted through a NATS broker?

Tags: ffmpeg, nestjs, video-streaming, html5-video, nats.io

I have an rtsp to mpegts streamer (ffmpeg wrapped in Express for publishing) that streams by publish to a NATS Jetstream.

```
const options =
     [
         "-rtsp_transport", "tcp",
         "-i", streamUrl,
         '-f', 'mpegts',
         '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
         '-c:v', 'h264',
         '-b:v', '800k',
         '-r', '30',
         '-muxdelay', '0.4',
         '-movflags', 'frag_keyframe+empty_moov',
         '-'
     ];
```

```
try {
         const natsConnection = await nats.connect({
             servers: 'ws://127.0.0.1:9222',
             preserveBuffers: true
         })

         conststream = spawn('ffmpeg', options);

         stream.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
             console log(chunk);
             natsConnection.publish('stream.1', chunk);
         });

         stream.stdout.on('error', (error) => {
             console.error('FFmpeg error:', error);
         });

         stream.stdout.on('close', (code) => {
             console.log('FFmpeg process closed with code:', code);
         });
     } catch (e) {
         console.error(e);
     }
```

It's all about the NestJS application signing up for this when the visitor follows the route.
The controller method itself

```
@get()
   async findOne(
     @Headers() headers,
     @Res() res,
   ) {
     const streamObservable = this.natsService.subscribeStreamEvents('1');

     // Set appropriate headers for video streaming
     res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');
     res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');

     res.status(200);

     // Write data chunks directly to the response
     const subscription = streamObservable.subscribe({
       next: (chunk) => {
         console.log('wwww', chunk);
         res.write(chunk);
       },
       error: (error) => {
         console.error('Error streaming video:', error);
       },
       complete: () => {
         res end();
       },
     });

     res.on('close', () => {
       subscription.unsubscribe();
     });
   }
```

Well, and service service

```
subscribeToCameraEvents(cameraId: string) {
     const subject = new Subject<any>();

     this.natsConnection.subscribe(`stream.${cameraId}`, {
       callback: (err, msg: Msg) => {
         if (err) {
           subject.error(err);
           return;
         }
         // console.log(msg.data);
         subject.next(msg.data);
       },
     });

     return subject.asObservable();
   }
```

The data is consoled as a Buffer.

trying to play the stream

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Video Streaming Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<video controls width="640" height="480" style="background: black">
     <source src="http://localhost:3301/api/streams" type="video/mp4">
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

the route is true in the source.

The problem is that through VLC and ffplay - localhost:3301/api/streams the stream is displayed, and everything works fine, without any additional settings.

And here in html does not want.

**What am I doing wrong? **

I will be glad to any comments and additional questions.

I have tried canvas and jsmpeg (not working too), @Res({passthrough: true}) - stream does not work in VLC, ffplay and html (without passthrough stream is working only in VLS and ffplay)